# Why my jQuery selector can't find my element by id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, primefaces

I have a code with a simple jQuery selector usage:

```
$("label").each(function () {
    var target = $("#" + $(this).attr("for"));
});
```

I'm using PrimeFaces, so the HTML looks like:

```
<label for="j_idt23:txtNumber">Number:</label>
<input id="j_idt23:txtNumber" name="j_idt23:txtNumber" type="text" value="0" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
```

But it raises an error: `"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: txtNumber"`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:` symbol is one of the selectors' wildcards used by jQuery (that like pointed in the comments, represents a pseudoclass for the element, i.e., `input:disabled`). So, it is trying to interpret `:` as a wildcard and not as a part of your `id`. jQuery think your id is `j_idt23` and the pseudoclass is `txtNumber` (wich is invalid, sure).

Just add the `\\` before it and jQuery will interpret as literal text.

Your code will look like this:

```
$("label").each(function () {
    var target = $("#" + $(this).attr("for").replace(":", "\\:"));
});
```

Comment: And why is you replacing with two \\?

Comment: The first \ is to escape the 2nd \

Comment: or change the id to not include `:`. I doubt it is officially allowed in an element id.

Comment: Because JavaScript uses \ as a wildcard for regular expressions. Then you need to put one more \, then JavaScript will interpret the other \ as literal text.

Comment: Thanks @beetstra and @ErickPetru. Now I understood and worked.

Comment: `:` is not a wildcard. It's a pseudo-class/element delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Since your using PrimeFaces there is a function `PrimeFaces.escapeClientId()` that will escape the JSF ID into a usable jQuery ID.

```
$("label").each(function () {
    var target = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId($(this).attr("for")));            
});
```

Comment: Great tip, I didn't know this method.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the wasy jQuery handles selectors:

```
# denotes an id: '#id'
. denotes a class: '.class'
: denotes a pseudo class: ':pseudo_class'
```

So when your doing your selection it is expanding to:

```
$("#j_idt23:txtNumber")
```

Meaning find an element with id = 'j_idt23' and pseudo class 'txtNumber' but txtNumber isnt a valid pseudo class, and jQuery is confused.

Change it to something like `"j_idt23_txtNumber"`

Comment: PrimeFaces create ids with this `:`. I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an other approach in JSF 2.0. If you're comfort with, try to change the separator char directly via "web.xml"

```
<context-param>
    <description>
        Declares the separator char for ids (default is ':')
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
    <param-value>§</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This context param changes the separator char globally, e.g. j_idt23:txtNumber becomes j_idt23§txtNumber.

Comment: I was pretty sure I knew a solution for this already... and there it is :P Not sure whether to use escapeClientId, though, since I somehow got used to colon separated IDs.